# Delta function of the Euclidean norm $\delta(|\mathbf x|)$ / in polar coordinates at origin $\delta(r)$

Tags: distribution-theory, polar-coordinates, dirac-delta, spherical-coordinates

Several posts discuss the representation of the delta function in polar coordinates in 2D or 3D, e.g. [Dirac delta in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates) or [Delta function at the origin in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951874/delta-function-at-the-origin-in-polar-coordinates)

Does anyone have a reference for a representation of $\delta(|\mathbf x|)$ or $\delta(r)$ in general dimension $n \geq 2$?  I am guessing the following:
$$ \delta(r)/r^{n-1} = s_{n-1} \delta(\mathbf x), \qquad s_{n-1} := {2\pi^{n/2} \over \Gamma(n/2)} \text{  (area of unit sphere)} $$
or equivalently (?)
$$
\delta(|\mathbf x|) = s_{n-1} |\mathbf x|^{n-1} \delta(\mathbf x)
$$

**My proof**: For $r_0 \neq 0$ the general curvilinear correspondence is
$$ \delta(\mathbf {x - x}_0) \equiv \delta(r - r_0) \delta(\mathbf u - \mathbf u_0) / r^{n-1}, \qquad \mathbf {x, x}_0\in\mathbb R^n\quad r,r_0>0\quad \mathbf{u, u}_0\in\mathbb S^{n-1} \text{  (unit sphere)} $$
The case $\mathbf x_0 = \mathbf 0 \Leftrightarrow (r_0 = 0, \mathbf u_0\in\mathbb S^{n-1})$ corresponds to a singular Jacobian of the transformation and we may "integrate out" all ignorable spherical coordinates $\mathbf u$:
$$ \begin{aligned}\delta(\mathbf x) \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} d\mathbf u 
& = \delta(r) / r^{n-1} \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \delta(\mathbf u - \mathbf u_0) d\mathbf u, \qquad\text{i.e.}
\\
s_{n-1} \delta(\mathbf x) & = \delta(r) / r^{n-1}
\end{aligned} $$
as required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will write $\omega_d := s_{d-1} = \frac{2\,\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$.

If $f(x) = \tilde{f}(|x|)$ with $\tilde{f}\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$, then for any $\varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\langle \tilde{f},\varphi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \tilde{f}(r)\,\varphi(r)\,\mathrm{d}r = \frac{1}{\omega_d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\frac{\varphi(|x|)}{|x|^{d-1}}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\omega_d}\left\langle f, \frac{\varphi(|x|)}{|x|^{d-1}}\right\rangle
$$
so if we want to define a generalization of the notion of radial change of variable, we might want to define $\tilde{f}(r)$ by setting
$$
\langle \tilde{f},\varphi\rangle := \frac{1}{\omega_d}\left\langle f, \frac{\varphi(|x|)}{|x|^{d-1}}\right\rangle
$$
in the general case. In particular, we will have the relation $\omega_d\,|x|^{d-1} \tilde{f}(|x|) = f(x)$. Remark however that the above definition does not make sense if we replace $f$ by $\delta_0$.
$$
\frac{\delta_0(x)}{|x|^{d-1}} \text{ is not a priori a well defined distribution}
$$
Defining $g(r) = \tilde{f}(|r|)$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$, we can however try to solve the equation $\omega_d\,r^{d-1} g(r) = \delta_0$.
Taking the Fourier transform ($\hat{g}(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\,e^{-2i\pi x\cdot y}\,\mathrm{d}x$) we get
$$
\frac{\omega_d}{(-2i\pi)^{d-1}} \hat{g}^{(d-1)} = 1
$$
so by integrating $d-1$ times, we get
$$
\hat{g}(y) = \frac{(-2i\pi)^{d-1}}{\omega_d} \left(\frac{y^{d-1}}{(d-1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{d-1} a_k\,x^{k-1}\right)
$$
so that (if I did not messed up with the power on the $-1$)
$$
g(r) = \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{\omega_d} \left(\frac{\delta_0^{(d-1)}}{(d-1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{d-1} C_k\,\delta_0^{(k-1)}\right)
$$
(where $\delta_0^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of the Dirac delta centered in $0$) and we can see that there is no uniqueness of $\delta_0(r)/r^{d-1}$ (which is natural since $x^n \delta_0^{(n-1)} = 0$). However, the Dirac is homogeneous, and thus so is its radial representation. Therefore
$$
g = \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{\omega_d\,(d-1)!} \,\delta_0^{(d-1)}
$$
which can be written in a more informal way with $r=|x|$
$$\boxed{
\delta_0(x) = \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{\omega_d\,(d-1)!} \,\delta_0^{(d-1)}(r)
}$$

---

**Remark:** Of course, we can now ***choose*** to define
$$
\frac{\delta_0(r)}{r^{d-1}} := \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{\,(d-1)!} \,\delta_0^{(d-1)}(r)
$$
as ***the homogeneous solution*** of the equation $r^{d-1} g(r) = \delta_0$, and so we find as you was writing $\omega_d\,\delta_0(x) = \frac{\delta_0(r)}{r^{d-1}}$, but now we know the true meaning of this notation.

Comment: I do not understand your $|λx| = λ^d|x|$. It should be $|λx| = λ\,|x|$. It seems to me it is the same homogeneity on both sides. Each derivative change your homogeneity of one, and so
$$
\lambda^{-1-(d-1)} = \lambda^{-d}
$$

Comment: My mistake, but I think there's still a mismatch: Taking x=λx homogeneity gives us $λ^{-d} δ_0(x)$ on the LHS, while RHS gives $\delta_0^{(d−1)}0(|λx|)=\delta_0^{(d−1)}(λ|x|)=λ^{−(d-1)} \delta_0^{(d−1)}(|x|)$ ???

Comment: My mistake again I got it $\delta_0^{(n)}$ is homogeneous of degree $-n-1$ and for $n=d-1$ the correct RHS is $\lambda^{-(d-1)-1} = \lambda^{-d}$ as you wrote.

Comment: To summarize your post in my notations: we both agree that $ \delta( x ) = \delta(| x|)/[s_{n-1} |x|^{n-1}]$ and you show that a sensible representation of $\delta(r)/r^{n-1}$ is $(-1)^{(n-1)} \delta^{(n-1)}(r) / (d-1)!$ which I think can also be obtained by repeatedly integrating a test function by parts.  Thus $$ \delta( x ) = \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)! s_{n-1} } \delta^{(n-1)}(| x |) $$ is also a possible formula.

Comment: Yes, exact. And the advantage of this representation is that it is a well defined distribution (i.e. we know its action on test functions) while this is not the case of $\delta_0(r)/r^{d-1}$. In distributions theory, one usually only defines the multiplication of elements that are in dual space of each other. As we see here, the multiplication of $\delta_0(r)$ with $1/r^{d-1}$ has no unique clear meaning.

Comment: Yes, for sure there is a direct proof without Fourier transform. I suppose it should work well using approximations of the Dirac distribution and then passing to the limit.