# Dirac distribution of a product: Simplifying an integral

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, dirac-delta

Let $X$ be a topological space, $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, $x_0\in X$ and $\delta(-,x_0)$ the Dirac-delta distribution. Then (abusing notation) we have $$\int_{x\in X}\delta(x,x_0)f(x)=f(x_0).$$

Next, consider a continuous function $f:X^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a similar formula involving the integral $$\int_{x\in X^n}\delta (f(x),x_0)f(x)?$$

I am mainly interested in the case that $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is the $n$-fold multiplication map, meaning $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n.$

I know that this is a vague and probably non-well posed question. I'm looking for something like "something similar appears/is considered here" or "maybe this could be relevant."

---

Background: The co-Yoneda lemma in category theory can be seen as a kind of categorification of the first identity (see Remark 2.3 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma)). I'm interested in a version of the second integral in the category world.

Comment: I suppose $f$ is missing in the second integral. I do not see your problem, just take $X = \Bbb R^n$

Comment: @LL3.14 I do not understand your comment. I edited the question. Maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: Oh I see it was a multiplication! Yes, it is more clear now. Then you might be interested by results of this kind 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263808/expression-for-dirac-delta-deltaxy/4264764#4264764

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [coarea formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607148/proof-of-relationship-between-dirac-delta-and-co-area-formula)?